# Selecting and updating a table simultaneously in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

We are trying to select some records in a table which are latest records for a combination of 3 columns.
Along with that we have to update the records which are not the latest for the combination of columns.

Please see the data we have as below:

```
SELECT * FROM TEST_RECORDS
```

[image]

Below is the query we are using

```
WITH FUNCTION UPDATEDUPLICATES(P_ACCOUNT VARCHAR2,
                               P_CCAID VARCHAR2,
                               P_REQSEQ NUMBER,
                               P_RANK NUMBER ) 
                               RETURN NUMBER IS
BEGIN
if P_RANK > 1
  THEN
  UPDATE TEST_RECORDS
     SET DOMAIN_ID = 2
   WHERE ACCOUNT_NUM = P_ACCOUNT
     AND CCAID = P_CCAID
     AND REQUEST_SEQ = P_REQSEQ;
     RETURN 1;
     ELSE
       RETURN 0;
END IF;

END;
RANKED_RECORDS AS(
  SELECT SR.*,
         RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY 
         ACCOUNT_NUM, 
         CUSTOMER_REF, 
         CCAID ORDER BY REQUEST_DTM DESC) R_RANK
    FROM TEST_RECORDS SR), 
UPDATESELECTED AS (
SELECT RR.*,UPDATEDUPLICATES(
                        RR.ACCOUNT_NUM,
                        RR.CCAID,
                        RR.REQUEST_SEQ,
                        RR.R_RANK
                       ) update_status
                       FROM RANKED_RECORDS RR
                  )
SELECT * FROM UPDATESELECTED;
```

But this query is throwing an error as below:

```
ORA-14551: cannot perform a DML operation inside a query 
ORA-06512: at line 9
ORA-06512: at line 20
```

I might be wrong in doing this and if yes, could any ne point me how to do a select as well as an update at the same time.

Comment: You should first update the records and then select it or otherwise declare your function as `PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried the below as suggested by Mohd. And its working.

```
WITH FUNCTION UPDATEDUPLICATES(P_ACCOUNT VARCHAR2,
                               P_CCAID VARCHAR2,
                               P_REQSEQ NUMBER,
                               P_RANK NUMBER ) 
                               RETURN NUMBER IS
PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;                               
BEGIN
if P_RANK > 1
  THEN
  UPDATE TEST_RECORDS
     SET DOMAIN_ID = 2
   WHERE ACCOUNT_NUM = P_ACCOUNT
     AND CCAID = P_CCAID
     AND REQUEST_SEQ = P_REQSEQ;
     commit;
     RETURN 1;
     ELSE
       RETURN 0;
END IF;

END;
RANKED_RECORDS AS(
  SELECT SR.*,
         RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY 
         ACCOUNT_NUM, 
         CUSTOMER_REF, 
         CCAID ORDER BY REQUEST_DTM DESC) R_RANK
    FROM TEST_RECORDS SR), 
UPDATESELECTED AS (
SELECT RR.*,UPDATEDUPLICATES(
                        RR.ACCOUNT_NUM,
                        RR.CCAID,
                        RR.REQUEST_SEQ,
                        RR.R_RANK
                       ) update_status
                       FROM RANKED_RECORDS RR
                  )
SELECT * FROM UPDATESELECTED
```

Answer (score 0):

Functions, unless autonomous transactions (which also means that it has to `COMMIT`), can't perform DML (as error says). I wouldn't recommend having it an autonomous transaction.

What to do? Write a **procedure** and update rows.

Comment: May I know what is the problem in having an autonomous  transaction? Ideally in my case the records I want to update are just obsolete records.

Comment: It commits transaction within the function, but not the "main" transaction. If something goes wrong, you have a problem because some rows are updated (and committed), while some are not, and who knows what happened *outside* the autonomous transaction ... They have their usage - maybe your case is one of those. Just be careful as you might solve one problem and cause even bigger one(s).

Comment: Yeah. Understood. But in my logic I am keeping the 1 row active even after updating them. Considering these,  in my requirement , I feel having autonomous transaction is ok. I am only updating the duplicate rows only without updating the latest one. So should be fine in my case.